# If $p$ is a prime number such that $2^n <p\leq 2^{n+1}$, then $p$ can not divide $a^{2^n}+1$ for all $a\in\mathbb{N}$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction

I want to show the following:

If $3\leq m\leq 2^{n+1}$, then $m$ can not divide $a^{2^n}+1$ for all $a\in\mathbb{N}$. The context is induction.

For $n=1$, it's enough calculate $(0^2, 1^2, 2^2)\equiv \pmod 3$ and $(0^2, 1^2, 2^2, 3^2)\equiv \pmod 4$.

Assume that it's true for $n$.

For $n+1:$ Suppose that $3\leq m\leq 2^{n+2}$ but $m\mid a^{2^{n+1}}+1=(a^2)^{2^n}+1.$ By induction hipotesis, we have that $2^{n+1}<m\leq 2^{n+2}.$

Claim: $m$ is prime.

If $m$ is not a prime number, then all it's divisors is at most $\frac{m}{2}\leq 2^{n+1}$. This is a contradiction by the induction hipotesis.

And now I need to prove the question in the title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $p\,\big|\,\left(a^{2^n}+1\right)$ then $a$ has order $2^{n+1}\pmod p$.  But that would imply that $$2^{n+1}\,\big|\,(p-1)$$

which contradicts the given inequality.